# Acute tendonitis

Tags: tendinopathy, tendinitis

I was diagnosed with acute tendonitis two months ago by a doctor, and prescribed voltaren. Two weeks after the diagnosis the pain still had not subsided, and I visited the doctor again and got a cortisol injection in the shoulder. The doctor did not say anything about how long the healing progress vould take, and I still feel pain within the shoulder (only when doing certain movements or applying some force). 
My question is how long should I wait, and/or is it necessary with a surgery.

Comment: Visit the doctor again as soon as you can

Comment: Go to the doctor. But you should know that unless something is totally wrong with your shoulder your doctor will probably recommend physiotherapy to make it heal faster. If mild pain is making you restrict certain movements then that may have caused the healing process to have stagnated. Excruciating pain is your body's stop signal, mild pain is the signal to take it easy. Movement is necessary for self-repair mechanisms to work well.